# what is avg without doing here

Tags: prometheus, promql

I see a PromQL which has been run against a node exporter on linux system as below:

```
avg without(cpu, mode)(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[1m]))
```

I can easily understand upto what the following is doing :

```
rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[1m]
```

But I didn't get what

```
avg without(cpu, mode)
```

is doing. What is the use of 
    without(cpu, mode)

Can you please help with it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) has details about the `without` clause:

> `without` removes the listed labels from the result vector`

In your case, the query should really be `avg (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[1m])) without (cpu, mode)` (`without` goes after `avg()`).

It will drop both labels `cpu` and `mode` (btw, mode is always `idle` anyway) and calculate the average idle cpu available per instance.

fyi, the same can also be achieved by using `by (instance)` instead of using `without(cpu, mode)`.

Comment: `without` can go between `avg` (or whatever the aggregation is) and its parenthesis. Some people (myself included) prefer it that way. And that is how Prometheus formats it on output (e.g. on its `/rules` page): `count without(instance) (up)`.

Comment: `by (instance)` is only equivalent to `without(cpu, mode)` if `instance`, `cpu` and `mode` are the only labels present. If any label is added via the scrape configuration (e.g. `env="prod"`) then they're no longer equivalent and whether you use one or the other depends on what you want to achieve: aggregate by instance only or aggregate away the `cpu` label only (and drop `mode` in the process).